# installing application on live Ubuntu off a dvd

Tags: software-installation, livedvd

I am using live Ubuntu off of a dvd without installation..is it possible to download application from Ubuntu Software or from Websites and install it?
please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  You have a real session when running `Try Ubuntu`.  The limitation is the drive size and the fact that every time you boot you will start over fresh.

The drive is a ram drive created from the available ram in your system.  If you have 8 gigs in your system. of course that would limit the drive size drastically.  When you subtract the amount of ram needed for actual system ram for applications you won't have much left.  That means you are very limited with how much you can download and install from the repositories.

Other than those two limitations, there isn't any significant difference between a full install and the `Try` session.

The `try ubuntu` option to browse around and get a feel for using Ubuntu.  Many useful programs and tools are installed in the environment by default.

With the limited amount of drive space you won't be able to install much more.  As per your comment, these are the steps to install `vlc`.

```
$ sudo apt update
$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt install vlc
```

Comment: file:///home/ubuntu/Pictures/Screenshot%20from%202016-10-25%2017-50-48.png it shows me this every time..what should i do?

Comment: The link you gave me will only link something that is on my actual computer.  I don't have the file on my computer.  Try copying and pasting text from the error so that I can read what you are seeing.  Or give me a link that starts with `http://`.  The `http://` is specifying the web.  The `file://` is specifying a file on the local computer.  By the way, lots of programs may require libraries that may only be available by executing `sudo update` and `sudo upgrade`.

Comment: i took a screenshot but don't know how to share

Comment: Did you get a popup where you can't copy and paste the message to the forum?  What command did you type in to produce the error you want to show?  I might be able to infer the knowing the command you executed.

Comment: I've tried to install vlc and when I try to download it shows "This link needs to be opened with an application. Send

Comment: it also shows two options AptURL and choose an application...what should i do?

Comment: Give me a few minutes to add the steps to my answer.